# How to write a vba loop like a c++ for loop

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I am wanting to write a loop similar to this:

```
for (int counter = 2; err.number != 0; counter ++ {
    bot.FindElementsByCss(".slicerCheckbox")([counter]).Click;
    }
```

how would I do that in vba: I currently have something like:

```
Dim counter As Integer
counter = 2
retry:
On Error Resume Next
bot.FindElementsByCss(".slicerCheckbox")([counter]).Click
if err.Number <> 0 then
   On Error GoTo -1
   On Error GoTo 0
   counter = counter + 1
   goto retry:
end if 
on error goto -1
on error goto 0
```

Comment: Is there not a better matching strategy? E.g. can you use xpath to target by a substring? Or a positional match in relation to some other element?

Comment: @QHarr there doesnt seem to be anything unique about the it to click. ```<div class="slicerCheckbox" aria-hidden="true">  <span class="glyphicon checkbox checkboxOutline" style="font-si: 10.6667px;"></span> </div> ```
the below is not clickable
```<span class="slicerText" title="4326790" style="color: rgb(255, 2! 255); background-color: rgb(26, 26, 26); border-style: solid; bon -color: rgb(96, 94, 92); border-width: Opx; font-size: 10.6667px; nt-family: Tahoma; line-height: 14px; font-weight: normal; font-s' e: normal; text-decoration: none;">4326790</span> </div> </div> </div> ```  
cont..

Comment: the first nth of slicer checkbox will always be elsewhere in the same place on the page. however on the dropbox itself even if there is only one item displayed the slicer checkbox , could be anything from 2 and I have seen up until the 50s or 60s.

Comment: Can you predict the displayed text for the desired checkbox?

Comment: @qharr yes, I can

Comment: then why not use xpath and insert the target text into the xpath? `FindElementByXPath("//span[contains(text(),'<some target text>')]")` 
or `FindElementByXPath("//span[text()='<some target text>']")` or potentially use css attribute selector `FindElementByCss("span[title='<some target text>']")`  My preference being for the latter.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the split html in comments. It may be that you would need to go the xpath route and move back up the DOM if the actual checkbox is a previous sibling or parent element. Likewise, for css you might need to set the initial returned match to an MSHTML element type that you can call .parent on or otherwise move up/back along the DOM.

Comment: @QHarr I will give it a try. the split would make more sense if you could see. there is a Slicer checkbox and a string of text next to it. when you click inspect element on the check box the above html code shows. however the first part applies to the check box and the second part applies to the string of text next to it. the string of text is not clickable.

Comment: @QHarr I gave the later one a try. It doesn't throw an error like object not interactable or anything. however it does not click the checkbox. ```.FindElementByCss("span[title='<4326790>']").click```

Comment: Yeah because you need to move back up to the checkbox I assume. Can you paste the html properly using a pastebin.com link or [edit] int question? I can then properly view the hierarchy maybe? Grab a parent node above these elements to be sure I can see the relationship.

Comment: @QHarr https://pastebin.com/Yq2gsDTH Note: in that the number is changed.  ```bot.FindElementByCss(".slicerItemContainer[aria-label= 'SoldTo 4262634'][role='checkbox']").Click ``` works. I have never thought about this and a google search didn't yield me anything. How would I pass a variable into the [aria-label= 'SoldTo 4262634'] tag. I tried declaring a string named test with "number" as the number known in advanced to be passed in: as  ```test ="'SoldTo " & number & "'" ``` which prints out 'SoldTo 4262634' and inserted it into ```[aria-label= test ]``` and that does not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243075/discussion-between-qharr-and-red).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a do loop

```
Dim counter as Integer
counter=2

Do 

    on error resume next
    bot.FindElementsByCss(".slicerCheckbox")([counter]).Click
    if err.number = 0 then exit do
    err.clear
    counter=counter+1

Loop
```

Comment: that does work.  is there any real difference between that in a while loop? such as: 
```while err.number <> 0 ``` 
...do the things
```wend```

Comment: also what is the difference between err.clear and on error goto -1/0?

Comment: While loops are deprecated. It is recommended to use Do Loops.  The specific difference is that you cannot exit in the middle of a while loop.  In your while proposal the err has not been created at the time of the test.  The difference between err.clear and on error goto -1 can be understood by using your eyes and google.

Comment: to specify, I understand that do while, has an exit and while does not and MS recommends to use the do/while. However, I remember also reading somewhere that do whiles should be avoided.

Comment: Unless you have a reference or context that's a pretty useless comment.  It is often observed that people use loops to select rows when instead they should be using the excel.find filter.

Comment: understood, it may have been for another language. I am using the loop to try and handle a drop down on a online powerBi report and bring the info into a spreadsheet. The nth element changes randomly on the same dropdown. sometimes it is the 2nd and sometimes it is something else, despite there only being one visible element on the ui

Answer (score 1):

Here, you are using selenium to click on several web elements.  It seems as though you are referencing them by number, counting up as you go.  You know that you have reached the end when you have an error referencing the web element by number.

I think you would be better off just capturing the whole set of elements, then clicking on each one.  That way, you don't have to respond to an error condition.

```
Sub process_elements()

    Dim elems As WebElements
    Dim elem As WebElement
  
    Set elems = bot.FindElementsByCss(".slicerCheckbox")
  
    For Each elem In elems
        elem.Click
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set elems = bot.FindElementsByCss(".slicerCheckbox")`  ? And `Dim elem As WebElement`  ?  In line with what I think your intention is. Without having the website and knowing what changes checkbox ticking will make we cannot be certain of no errors, However, are they not skipping index one at least? I've lost track with selenium in different languages as to whether indexing will be from 0 or 1 for the collection but you could amend the css selector to use nth-child or nth-of-type ranges potentially. You could also use for loop to elems.count (from correct start index) and index in during loop.

Comment: I'm no expert in selenium, but I think the error is happening because he's trying to reference an HTML object that does not exist.  If clicking an object causes an error, it will be a JS error, not a VB error, so it will not be catchable.  Besides, there is no other way to end the loop.

Comment: @Gove that gives a type misMatch error. Reason why I am trying to catch the error is because I do not know how many of that slicer box there are. On the page UI it shows only one item in the dropdown. However, when you inspect the element, select it, and find all. there could be two of them all the way up to 54 on the page. Sometimes on the very same dropdown box, the one I want is (".slicerCheckbox")([2]) and sometimes it changes to 5.

Comment: and other times it is something completely random *

Comment: @Red.  I see my mistake, I'll edit the code by removing the "([coutner])" from the "set elems = ..." line.  Without having access to the URL you are working with, I can't test my solution.

Comment: I see, unfortunately  I can't provide access. it is a password protected online power bi report that I can't use any sql for the table view to create my own version as I do not have access to the server. I will test your correction.

Comment: You've dim elems twice when the second should be elem. See my first comment. That needs to be fixed. Hope this doesn't feel like trolling. Trying to help.

Comment: @QHarr.  Not like trolling at all.  Thanks for catching that.  Updating code now...   That's always the risk when you don't have the ability to test the code.

Comment: @Gove tested it. clicks the first nth of the element, without clicking the visible one in the dropbox it will then close it(just does this for first nth), then it will attempt to click the next one and since the drop box is closed, throws an error that the element is not interactable. (the very first nth of it does appear to be always elsewhere on the page. I tried adding ```if elem <> 1 then elem.click  and tried If elem <> bot.FindElementsByCss(".slicerCheckbox")([1]) Then``` however both of those say object not supported. After the first iteration, if I manually open back up it will work.

Comment: @Red, sorry I can't help more.  I'm not an expert with selenium.  I teach one lecture on it at University.  It may help you get a more solid footing.  Here's a link to a video of what I cover in class.  https://vba-course.blogspot.com/2021/08/controlling-chrome-with-selenium-and-vba.html